# Emacs mode for exploring/managing pgp/gpg

Tags: gpg, pgp

Is there Emacs mode for exploring/managing pgp/gpg keys?

Like starting from `gpg --list-keys` find individual info about key, refresh it, see web of trust, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [EasyPG](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/epa.html)

You can list keys with:
<kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>epa-list-keys</kbd>.

Comment: Wow. I searched for something in `M-x list-packages` and it is build-in ))